# Can a solar flare or coronal mass ejection cause a planet to heat up?

Tags: planets

There is this setting I wish to use of a planet tidal locked to a red dwarf, in a Goldilocks/habitable zone/distance, that gets turned into, mostly, a desert due to a coronal mass ejection or a solar flare from its star.

I know these solar events take out electrical devices if strong enough but I was wondering....

Can they also heat up a planet to the extent of turning it to a desert?
And how fast could a coronal mass ejection from a red dwarf turn a planet into a desert? Decades, centuries, millennium?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Tosk. Does [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/42678/6986) about the same topic answer your question?

Comment: Thank you Frostfyre and indeed it does ^^

Comment: Thank you for confirming. We like to keep repeat topics neatly connected, so I've flagged this question as a duplicate of the other. If you have other questions, feel free to create a separate post to address them. Enjoy your time with us!